# C++ error: request for member 'push_back' in 'v'

Tags: c++, oop

Why do I get this error? I am at a loss...

error: request for member `push_back` in `v`, which is of non-class type `std::vector<Leaf, std::allocator<Leaf> >*`

```
class Leaf 
{
public:

    // Variables
    std::string *name;

    // Methods
    Leaf(){}
    Leaf(std::string *s)
    {
        name = s;
    }
};

class Branch 
{
public:

    // Variables
    Branch::Branch *parent;
    Branch::Branch *child;
    std::vector<Leaf> *children;
    std::string *name;

    // Methods
    Branch(std::string *s)
    {
        children = new std::vector<Leaf>;
        name = s;
    }
};

class Tree 
{
public:

    // Variables
    Branch::Branch *current;

    // Methods
    Tree(string *name)
    {
        current = new Branch::Branch(name);
    }

    void addBranch(Branch::Branch *newBranch)
    {
        this->current->child = newBranch;
        newBranch->parent = this->current;
    }

    void addLeaf(Leaf::Leaf *leaf)
    {
        std::vector<Leaf> *v = this->current->children;
        v.push_back(leaf);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the function `addLeaf()` v is a pointer, and leaf is a pointer, you need to dereference both of them.

```
v->push_back(*leaf);
```

Also, what's with all the scope qualifications, like `Leaf::Leaf` and `Branch::Branch`?  It should just be `Leaf`, and `Branch`.

Answer (score 0):

`v` is a pointer to a vector. Use a `->` instead of a `.`. i.e. `v->push_back(whatsit)`